# Repeated "Save Tag Edits" Bug when reviewing?

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tags

I was reviewing a few First Posts on Stackoverflow.

I went to edit the tags for one of them after refreshing the page and it showed up about 14 times. I believe it's a bug, even though I would completely say it's a feature.

Not sure if the browser matters but I'm using Chrome, no stack apps/scripts.

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Go to Review First Posts
2. Find a Question with tags...
3. Refresh Page
4. Go to the post by clicking the title (same tab)
5. Click retag, then cancel
6. Go back, Go back, Back until your back to the review
7. Press the retag on the Review Post.

Unfortunately I've gotten it a few different ways but none are consistent. Still trying.

[image]

Comment: Did you save them though? ;)

Comment: @Bart haha no, a few more and I would've.

Comment: @Nate we do see how you could get this to happen - however do you have steps that will reproduce this every time?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas yea, just figured out how to do it again. (refer to edit) 
But its inconsistent I'm still looking for a perfect reproduction.

Comment: @nate we pushed another build that we think might fix this issue since it was inconsistent.  Can you test a bit more and let us know if it's still happening?

Comment: @GeoffDalgas yea will do. Can you check out my recent question though? I believe that might be a priority.

Comment: @GeoffDalgas I wasn't able to reproduce the problem again after your fix. I'll let you know if I ever find it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is fixed and pushed to production.  We believe it was due to calling the tag editor init multiple times.  Please let us know if you are still having an issue.