# Reviewing Posts - Retagging Bug

Tags: bug, status-deferred, tags

While trying to figure out this problem: [Repeated "Save Tag Edits" Bug when reviewing?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148625/repeated-save-tag-edits-bug-when-reviewing)

I came across another (I believe it is) bug. This one however is a bit different.

When you go to review a post if you retag then click save changes, the save changes you actually didn't make, the "I'm done" button becomes enabled and when you click it, it gives you credit for the review.

Hope this is fixed so people don't take advantage of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We know there are a few edge cases around review where you could get credit for reviewing a post where no work was performed.  These are fairly easy to detect and remove.  We will continue to make review more robust but right now are focused on driving all of our review tasks forward.

Comment: Ok, sounds good!